# Creating an asynchronous SendingRequest2 event handler for Microsoft.OData.Client with IODataClientHandler

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, odata

I am working on building an integration that interacts with an OAuth secured OData service. To handle the OAuth portion of the application, I created a dedicated service (`AccessTokenClient`) that uses an `HttpClient` to fetch and renew access tokens. Because I'm executing external requests to get this token, this is performed asynchronously.

The `Microsoft.OData.Extensions.Client` includes an interface (`IODataClientHandler`) that allows you to customize the `Microsoft.OData.Client`'s creation behavior via its `OnClientCreated` method. If I create an event handler for the client's `SendingRequest2` event, I can customize the messages sent through the client by updating the message's headers before it's sent.

For example, here's a working bit of code that calls my token client and sets the authorization token on the outbound message:

```cs
public void OnClientCreated(ClientCreatedArgs args)
{
    var client = args.ODataClient;
    client.SendingRequest2 += (s, e) =>
    {
        var token = _tokenClient.GetAccessToken().Result;
        
        e.RequestMessage.SetHeader(
            AppConstants.Authorization, 
            $"{AppConstants.Bearer} {token.Token}");
    };
}
```

In an effort to avoid deadlocking my application, I tried to set the handler to be asynchronous like so:

```cs
public void OnClientCreated(ClientCreatedArgs args)
{
    var client = args.ODataClient;
    client.SendingRequest2 += async (s, e) =>
    {
        var token = await _tokenClient.GetAccessToken();
        
        e.RequestMessage.SetHeader(
            AppConstants.Authorization, 
            $"{AppConstants.Bearer} {token.Token}");
    };
}
```

I expected the application to perform like before, but what actually ends up happening is the token client begins to execute (as confirmed by logs), but the OData client simply executes without ever receiving a bearer token. If I add a logging line in between the token fetch and the assignment, it does not get hit in the asynchronous code.

How can I update my code to asynchronously populate the access token?

Answer (score 0):

The common solution to use `async` logic to prepare auth tokens is to implement a `DelegatingHandler` that evaluates *after* the ODataClient has finished preparing the request and has handed it over to HttpClient. The reason that we can use `async` logic in this context is that the caller for this method specifically implements an `asynchronous` context and is expecting a `Task` to be returned.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
...
/// <summary>
/// Middleware for Delegating HTTP calls and injecting Auth
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>We cannot register Delegating Handlers as Singletons across all scopes, they must be recreated with the associated scoped HttpClient so use a Scoped or Transient service registration that matches the lifetime of the HttpClient</remarks>
public class BearerTokenAuthHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    AccessTokenClient _tokenClient;
    public BearerTokenAuthHandler(AccessTokenClient accessTokenClient)
    {
        _tokenClient = accessTokenClient;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = await _tokenClient.GetAccessToken();
        request.Headers.Authorization = 
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AppConstants.Bearer, token.Token);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The following is an example of the DI registration of this handler for OData, taken from a Blazor application:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<BearerTokenAuthHandler>();
builder.Services.AddODataClient()
    .ConfigureODataClient(odata =>
    {
        odata.HttpRequestTransportMode = HttpRequestTransportMode.HttpClient;
        odata.AddAndUpdateResponsePreference = DataServiceResponsePreference.IncludeContent;
        odata.Format.UseJson();
        odata.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
    })
    .AddHttpClient()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenAuthHandler>();
```

I realize that the comments on [`SendingRequest2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/using-hooks#sendingrequest2) indicate this is a method you can use to set the *authentication information like token or cert name*. But the calling implementation, and the fact that it is implemented as an *event* preclude the use of `async` logic. The was OK and relevant back in WCF services days but you cant use any blocking logic in this context.

You CAN NOT use `async` event handlers if you require your logic to be executed *before* the event is processed. Events in C# are explicitly implemented in a *synchronous* pattern.

---

We run into this a lot, especially with a runtime like Blazor Web Assembly. ODataClient uses events to prepare the message *before* delegating to the underlying HttpClient messagaing pipline. The net effect of this is that if you use asynchronous implementations for the event handlers, the asynchronous logic might be executed *after* the underlying pipeline has completed, or at least progressed to a state where the arguments passed in the event have been consumed, disposed, or are no longer relevant at the specific point in time that your async logic executes.

- Some of these states will result in exceptions being raised, but due to the method returning `void` (which it MUST if it is an event handler) the exceptions will not be caught at all.

  > If I add a logging line in between the token fetch and the assignment, it does not get hit in the asynchronous code.

  This sounds like the exceptional situation, preventing your code from executing at all.

Read more about the [DataServiceContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataservicecontext?view=odata-client-7.0) events in [Client hooks in OData client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/using-hooks)
This is an over-simplification pseudo workflow of the process:

1. Begin ODataClient action
2. fire [`BuildingRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataservicecontext.buildingrequest?view=odata-client-7.0) event
3. fire [`SendingRequest2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataservicecontext.sendingrequest2?view=odata-client-7.0) event
4. Call `SendAsync` on the underlying HttpClient

...

9. ... Complete any async Task that was started in step 2.
10. ... Complete any async Task that was started in step 3.

***NOTE:** 9 and 10 are executed at an indeterminable point in time and sequence.*

The `DelegatingHandler` is called in a chained pattern from the `HttpClient` at step 4 in the above list as described in [HttpClient Message Handlers in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers).

[image: Delegating Handlers in Http Client]